# How to split the data for speaker verification using AAM Softmax loss?

Tags: training, loss-function, speaker-verfication

- There are several models for speaker verificaiton task (wavlm-ecapa / xvector / ...).
- Some of those model where trained with **AAM Softmax loss**, which gets the number of labels as input.
- When training speaker verificaiton task, we would **split** the data to train and validate (i.e **different speakers** in train set and **different speaker** in validaion set).
- If the train and validation datasets have different number of speakers, how can we train the model while using AAM Softmax loss ?